# Creating a materialized view in Oracle on another view without going stale/needs compile status

Tags: oracle, view

I have the following view that is based on Oracle E-Business suite supplied tables. I want to create a materialized view in another schema that is based on this view. The materialized view will then be used in Oracle Application Express (APEX) app. I created the materialized view as BUILD IMMEDIATE, REFRESH COMPLETE, ON DEMAND and then created a refresh group to refresh once a day and assigned this materialized view to that refresh group. When the data was updated on one of the base tables, the materialized view became stale and the status said 'Needs compilation'. I can understand that it's due to the materialized view being out of sync with the base view since the data changed in the base view. The problem is, it made 4 other Oracle E-Business suite supplied materialized views invalid. I'm not sure why or how. I then dropped the refresh group, materialized view, and then created again with REFRESH START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE+1. When I did that and then accessed that materialized view through the APEX application, it ran fine the first time, but then the query hung the second time. I checked and the MV went to a stale state (without any update to the base table data) and caused one of the Oracle EBS supplied MV to go invalid also. The query hung because the MV went to the "Needs compile" state. I am not sure what was causing the issue. I then thought I would create a fast refresh instead of complete. The examples I see for fast refreshes require materialized view logs based on the base table with a primary key or row id. I use a view that has multiple tables. I am not sure how to create the logs. Also, I believe I have to use ON DEMAND (and not ON COMMIT) since I am using a view with multiple tables. Also, how do I prevent the MV from going stale with the "needs compile" status? Any guidance on this is appreciated.

```
Here is the view statement.

>  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW APPS.SIUPER_PE_FISCAL_OFFICER_V
>     (
>         FISCAL_OFFICER_NAME,
>         FISCAL_OFFICER_ID,
>         FISCAL_OFFICER_EMAIL,
>         EMPLOYEE_NAME,
>         ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER,
>         ASSIGNMENT_ID,
>         EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
>         EMPLOYEE_ID
>     )
>     BEQUEATH DEFINER
>     AS
>         SELECT DISTINCT
>                INITCAP (SUBSTR (ffv.ATTRIBUTE4, 1, 50))     fiscal_officer_name,
>                usr.employee_id                              fiscal_officer_id,
>                usr.email_address                            fiscal_officer_email,
>                e.full_name                                  employee_name,
>                a.assignment_number,
>                a.assignment_id,
>                e.employee_number,
>                e.person_id                                  employee_id
>           FROM APPS.PAY_COST_ALLOCATIONS_F       c,
>                APPS.PAY_COST_ALLOCATION_KEYFLEX  pcak,
>                APPS.FND_FLEX_VALUES              ffv,
>                APPS.FND_FLEX_VALUES_TL           ffvt,
>                apps.per_all_assignments_f        a,
>                apps.per_all_people_f             e,
>                apps.per_jobs                     j,
>                apps.per_job_definitions          jd,
>                apps.siugl_officer_v              ov,
>                apps.fnd_user                     usr
>          WHERE     a.person_id = e.person_id
>                AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN e.effective_start_date
>                                        AND e.effective_end_date
>                AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN a.effective_start_date
>                                        AND a.effective_end_date
>                AND (   a.assignment_status_type_id = '1'
>                     OR a.assignment_status_type_id = '141' 
>                     OR a.assignment_status_type_id = '161' 
>                     OR a.assignment_status_type_id = '461') 
>                AND a.job_id = j.job_id
>                AND (j.date_to IS NULL OR j.date_to >= TRUNC (SYSDATE))
>                AND SUBSTR (j.name, 1, 1) <> 'E'
>                AND j.job_definition_id = jd.job_definition_id
>                AND a.ASSIGNMENT_ID = c.ASSIGNMENT_ID
>                AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN c.effective_start_date
>                                        AND c.effective_end_date
>                AND c.proportion <> '0'
>                AND pcak.COST_ALLOCATION_KEYFLEX_ID = c.COST_ALLOCATION_KEYFLEX_ID
>                AND pcak.SEGMENT3 = ffv.FLEX_VALUE
>                AND ffv.value_category = 'SIUGL_BP'
>                AND ffv.FLEX_VALUE_ID = ffvt.FLEX_VALUE_ID
>                AND ov.name = ffv.attribute4
>                AND usr.user_name = ov.userid_id
>                AND (usr.end_date IS NULL OR usr.end_date >= TRUNC (SYSDATE));
>
```

Here is the MV I tried first which made 4 other Oracle supplied MVs invalid and went to stale state and needed recompile/manual refresh.

> ```
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.SIUPER_PE_FISCAL_OFFICER_MV
> BUILD IMMEDIATE 
> REFRESH COMPLETE
> ON DEMAND
> AS
> SELECT * FROM APPS.SIUPER_PE_FISCAL_OFFICER_V
> /
> BEGIN
>   DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(
>     ownname => 'APEX_EBS_EXTENSION',
>     tabname => 'SIUPER_PE_FISCAL_OFFICER_MV');
> END;
> /
> BEGIN
>    DBMS_REFRESH.make(
>      name                 => 'APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.SIUPER_PE_FO_REFRESH',
>      list                 => '',
>      next_date            => SYSDATE,
>      interval             => 'SYSDATE + 1',
>      implicit_destroy     => FALSE,
>      lax                  => FALSE,
>      job                  => 0,
>      rollback_seg         => NULL,
>      push_deferred_rpc    => TRUE,
>      refresh_after_errors => TRUE,
>      purge_option         => NULL,
>      parallelism          => NULL,
>      heap_size            => NULL);
> END;
> /
>
> BEGIN
>    DBMS_REFRESH.add(
>      name => 'APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.SIUPER_PE_FO_REFRESH',
>      list => 'APEX_EBS_EXTENSION.SIUPER_PE_FISCAL_OFFICER_MV');
> END;
> /
> ```

Comment: If you create a materialized view with complete refresh on demand once per day, why do you care about the `COMPILE_STATE`? You know that you query *stale* data in the MV and you may check the columns `LAST_REFRESH_DATE` to see what state you have.

Comment: When it goes to stale state, the query that the APEX application uses takes 5-10 minutes to get the data instead of few seconds (when it's not stale). Also, this MV makes 4 other Oracle supplied MVs invalid. I am not sure why.